# How to release NSURLConnection in iPhone(Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I've used this line of code in many places of my project under various functions:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];
```

Now I'm getting an usual warning "Unused variable theConnection". 
I also know that its leaking memory.

Can use the following code?

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];
[theConnection release];
```

If I release theConnection object will it be problem in delegate methods like didReceiveData, connectionDidFinishLoading etc?

And if above statement can solve the memory leak without problem how to get rid of warning "Unused variable blah blah.."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I don't think this will show the warning

Or I think you can also try making the connection object as an instance variable of the class.

```
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];
```

You can avoid the leak by release `theConnection` based on your code in `dealloc` or some other method

Comment: Does this line : '[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];'

does not leak memory?

Comment: Yes thats why I gave you another option in my answer

Comment: If I use `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];` instead of `NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];` then using analyzer I'm getting warning about POTENTIAL MEMORY LEAK.

:(

Comment: Yes you will get memory leak thats why I provided you the option to make it an iVar.

Answer (score 1):

```
Now I'm getting an usual warning "Unused variable theConnection". I also know that its leaking memory.
```

The reason of getting the warning because you are not using `theConnection` object,

if you do'nt want delgate function not to be called for this instance set your `delegate` as `nil` instead of `self`

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
```

**EDITED:**

**In your .h class :**

```
NSURLConnection* m_URLConnection;
```

**In .m class :**

```
-(id) init
{
  m_URLConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil];
}
-(void) dealloc
{
  [m_URLConnection release];
  m_URLConnection = nil ;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I want the delegates to be called!
:)
What should I do now?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer but I've used my line of code so many times that it's almost impossible to change the complete code structure.

It would be much appreciated if you can provide a solution where I don't need to change the code structure. :)